# Adding C++ custom action in Visual studio installer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

due to some constraints i want to write a custom action in c++ and add its assembly in Visual Studio installer... is it possible?
as i know about c# or vb in those one can create classes inherited from Installer and it worked but now i want the same with C++....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured out that the assembly should contain a function named Install() in c++... it serves as an installer entry point.. added as Install custom action MSI installer executes that function .